# Is there a way to upload files from a google drive folder into a GCP bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

I have employees who upload csv files into google drive folders on a daily basis. The data in these files needs to be consolidated, cleaned and loaded onto a DB which then in turn connects to a visualization tool. I'm looking at using GCP's solutions. I'd like to automate the data ingestion process between the files being dropped into the google drive folder and the same files being uploaded onto the GCP buckets.

I had initially thought that I could do this through the GCP console but there seems to be no such UI option. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You can check from this link : https://philipplies.medium.com/transferring-data-from-google-drive-to-google-cloud-storage-using-google-colab-96e088a8c041